# Use both regular and preemptible machines in Nextflow and Google Lifesciences

Tags: nextflow

Consider having three processes, that run after one another. The first one must not be preempted, the second one can be preempted and the third one must not be preempted.

My config looks like this:

```
google {
    project = "cool-name"
    region = "cool-region"
    
    lifeSciences {
        bootDiskSize = "200 GB"
        debug = true
        preemptible = false
    }
}
```

Using `preemptible = false` like this, all of the three processes cannot be preempted. Is it somehow possible to make the second process preemptible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a [process selector](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) (i.e. `withName` or `withLabel`) to specify the required config option(s) for your process:

```
process {
    withName: 'second_process' {
        google.lifeSciences.preemptible = true
    }
}
```

This *should* override the 'default' value you specified in your config for your second process only.

---

Here's an example, just using the [echo](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#echo) directive:

Contents of `test.nf`:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process second_process {

    script:
    "echo HelloWorld"
}

workflow {

    second_process()
}
```

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
process {
    withName: 'second_process' {
        echo = true
    }
}
```

Run using:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false test.nf
```

Example output:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 20.10.0
Launching `test.nf` [nauseous_linnaeus] - revision: 6c35b71798
[78/cc161d] Submitted process > second_process
HelloWorld
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this does not work: ```"Unknown config attribute `process.withLabel:second_process` -- check config file: /home/username/blabla/nextflow.config"```

Comment: @r0f1: So what does your config file look like? Looks like you've specified 'withLabel' so your 'second_process' would also need the [label](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#label) directive set (with `label 'second_process'`). I've added an example above that just uses 'withName' to show that setting config for a specific process does actually work. I can't test any google directive right now, but you should at least get a better error message if the google.lifeSciences.preemptible config doesn't work for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks, I tried again and I figured out an interesting behavior: Using `echo = True` AND `google.lifeSciences.preemptible = true` in the same "withName" definition does work. However, using `google.lifeSciences.preemptible = true` alone, gives me this error I described. Thanks for your help, and also thanks for pointing me towards the DSL version 2; did not know that one.

Comment: No worries @r0f1. I wonder if setting both just masks the error and you get a preemptible by chance? I'll try investigate a bit more next week. Please let me know if you find a solution. Cheers.